# Django OneToOneField doesn't not allow null values during clone process

Tags: django

Lets say I have the following models:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
  uuid = models.CharField()

class Order(models.Model):
  cart = models.OneToOneField('Cart')
```

When I want to clone a cart:

```
cart.id = None
cart.order = None
cart.save()
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign None: "Cart.order" does not allow null values.
```

Comment: If you want to keep the order mandatory, you need to clone it as well.

Comment: I don't want to clone the order, I just want to clone the cart

Comment: In that case, make the cloned cart pointing to the same order than the original cart. What's your use case by the way? Why do you want to duplicate a Cart instance - maybe there is an easier way?

Comment: @François my case is not completely necessary and can be worked around by copying field by field, the question is more about the behaviour of django ORM.

Comment: Well OneToOneField default is a mandatory relationship (not nullable and constraint in SQL). I insist, why do you want to clone the order?

Answer (score 4):

try this :

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField()

class Order(models.Model):
    cart = models.OneToOneField('Cart',blank=True,null=True)
```